# Set SelectedItem of ComboBox from object

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, combobox

I'm building an MVVM Light WPF app in Visual Studio 2015 with Entity Framework 6 (EF) providing the data. I have a `ComboBox` that displays the reasons why someone needs to take a drug test and it looks like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ReasonsForTest}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ReasonsForTestVm,
                     UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Description" />
```

The `ReasonsForTest` is of type `ReasonForTestViewModel` class:

```
public class ReasonForTestViewModel: ViewModelBase
{
    private int _ReasonForTestId;
    private string _ReasonForTestAbbr;
    private string _description;

    public int ReasonForTestId
    {
        get { return _ReasonForTestId; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _ReasonForTestId) return;
            _ReasonForTestId = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string ReasonForTestAbbr
    {
        get { return _ReasonForTestAbbr; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _ReasonForTestAbbr) return;
            _ReasonForTestAbbr = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get { return _description; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _description) return;
            _description = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

I have a data service class that contains the following code to fetch the data for the valid values of the `ComboBox`:

```
public async Task<ObservableCollection<ReasonForTestViewModel>> GetReasonsForTest()
{
    using (var context = new MyEntities())
    {
        var query = new ObservableCollection<ReasonForTestViewModel>
            (from rt in context.ReasonForTests
             orderby rt.description
             select new ReasonForTestViewModel
             {
                 ReasonForTestId = rt.ReasonForTestID,
                 ReasonForTestAbbr = rt.ReasonForTestAbbr,
                 Description = rt.description,
             });
        return await Task.Run(() => query);
    }
}
```

The view model populates the `ComboBox` using this:

```
var dataService = new TestDataService();    
ReasonsForTest = await dataService.GetReasonsForTest();
```

The `ComboBox` has the correct data; however, it's not selecting the correct value when the app starts -- it's showing blank on load. The `SelectedItem` (`ReasonsForTestVm`) is also of that class type `ReasonForTestViewModel` and gets populated from the database with the one item for this person. I've stepped through the code to ensure `ReasonsForTestVm` has the correct data, and it does.

Here's the property for `ReasonsForTestVm`:

```
public ReasonForTestViewModel ReasonForTestVm
{
    get
    {
        return _reasonForTestVm;
    }

    set
    {
        if (Equals(value, _reasonForTestVm)) return;
        _reasonForTestVm = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? I'm about to lose my mind!

**Update**: Sorry for the confusing name in the property above. Fixed.

Comment: `ItemsSource="{Binding ReasonsForTest}"` -- What is `ReasonsForTest`? Is it a collection of `ReasonForTestViewModel`? Can we see the declaration of that and of the `ReasonsForTestVm` property? You say "The ReasonsForTest class is like this", but then you have a definition of `ReasonForTestViewModel`. Was that a typo?

Comment: Thanks, @EdPlunkett. `ReasonsForTest` is of type `ReasonForTestViewModel`. I'll update question above

Comment: What is `ValidReasonForTestViewModel `? And did you override `Equals`? Every time I override `Equals` it's a nightmare. Can I see the `ReasonsForTest` property definition too?

Comment: Did you try adding `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High` to the SelectedItem binding and seeing what you see in the Output window in VS?

Comment: @EdPlunkett: Sorry for the wrong name on that property. Fixed it.

Comment: SelectedItem should always be an instance from ItemsSource.  If the instance in SelectedItem isn't in ItemsSource, the UI won't update as expected.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, how do you do the `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High` on the SelectedItem binding?

Comment: `ItemsSource="{Binding ReasonsForTest, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"` Did you check out Will's suggestion?

Comment: @Will, both the collection that populates the ComboBox and the SelectedItem are of the same type: `ReasonForTestViewModel`.

Comment: No, not the same *type*.  Read carefully:  The ***instance*** within ItemsSource must be found within the collection bound to SelectedItem.  For example, if SelectedItem is bound to `public Items[] Foo { get; } = new[]{ new Item(), new Item() };`, you MUST use one of the items in Foo for SelectedItem: `SelectedItem = Foo[0];`.  If you do `SelectedItem = new Item();`, ***even if they are equivalent,*** the UI will not behave as expected because the instance in SelectedItem is not found in ItemsSource--it is equivalent to one of the instances, but it is **not that instance**.

Comment: @Will, now I get you: So the `SelectedItem` has to be one of the exact instances from the OC that populates the ComboBox. Now it finally clicked! So, I would have to search the `ItemsSource` OC for the one that should be selected, and then pass that one to the `SelectedItem`.

Comment: Yeah, try that and see if that was your problem.  Sorry, don't have a bunch of time to examine your code, but I do think that might be the issue.

Comment: That got it, @Will! Can you throw this into an answer and I'll accept it? Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any WPF items control that extends [Selector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector(v=vs.110).aspx) (such as ComboBox and ListBox) has two properties that are often used in conjunction:  `ItemsSource` and `SelectedItem`.

When you bind a collection to `ItemsSource`, a representation of those items are shown in the UI.  Each one of the representations is bound to an instance found within the collection bound to `ItemsSource`.  If, for an example, you're using a DataTemplate to create that representation, you'll find within each that the DataContext will be one of those instances from the collection.

When you *select* one of these representations, the `SelectedItem`property now holds the instance from the collection that was bound to that representation.

This works perfectly through user interaction with the UI.  However, there's one important caveat when interacting with these controls *programmatically*.

It's a very common pattern to bind these properties to similar properties in your view model.

```
public class MuhViewModel
{
    public MuhItems[] MuhItems {get;} = new[]{ new Item(1), new Item(2) };

    // I don't want to show INPC impls in my sample code, kthx
    [SuperSlickImplementINotifyPropertyChangedAttribute]
    public MuhSelectedItem {get;set;}
}
```

bound to

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MuhItems}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding MuhSelectedItem}" />
```

If you try to manually update the selected item this way...

```
muhViewModel.MuhSelectedItem = new Item(2);
```

The UI will *not* change.  The Selector sees that `ItemsSource` has changed, yes, but it doesn't find that instance in the `ItemsSource` collection.  It doesn't know that one instance of Item with a value of 2 is equivalent to any other Item with the same value.  So it does nothing.  (That's a bit simplistic for what really happens.  You can bust out JustDecompile and see for yourself.  It gets real convoluted down in there.)

What you should be doing in this situation is updating `SelectedItem` with an instance found within the collection bound to `ItemsSource`.  In our example,

```
var derp = muhViewModel.MuhItems.FirstOrDefault(x => x.MuhValue == 2);
muhViewModel.MuhSelectedItem = derp;
```

Side note, when tracking instances within a debug session, it helps to use Visual Studio's [Make Object ID](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/03/04/make-object-id/) feature.